# How do I get the key and it's object from a JSON file in c# using JSON.net?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JSON file like this

```
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
    }
```

and a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        private string key;
        private string object;

        public double Key
        {
            get { return key; }
            set { key = value; }
        }

        public string Object
        {
             get { return object; }
             set { object = value; }
        }

         public MyClass(string key, string object)
        {
                this.key = key;
                this.object = object;
        }
    }
```

And ideally I want to get a `List<String>` with the values from the JSON file. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What is `Key` and `Object` here? is `Key`[key1,key2,key3] and `Object` [value1,value2,value3] ?

Comment: @AVKNaidu Yes, exactly.

Comment: `key` and `value` are reversed in the JSON compared to how it is usually presented

Comment: @Plutonix My mistake, I edited it.

Comment: that would easily deserialize as a dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deserialize into a dynamic object, then access directly what value you want:

```
dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(yourJson);
string key1 = obj.key1;
string key2 = obj.key2;
string key3 = obj.key3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just deserialize this JSON into a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

Then if you just want a list of values you can do:

```
var values = dict.Values.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class similar to your json structure, you can use http://json2csharp.com/

   ```
     public class MyClass

     {

     public string key1 { get; set; }

     public string key2 { get; set; }

     public string key3 { get; set; }

     }
   ```
2. Create a method taking the json as input parameter and add the values to the list, then return it.

> ```
> public list<string> GetValues(MyClass myClassObjects)
> {
> list<String> valueList = new list<String>();
> for(int i=0; i< myClassObjects[0].count ; i++)
> {
> valueList.add(myClassObjects[0][i].toString());
> }
> return valueList;
> }
> ```